# How to order records by created_at last 3 days first, then by another column, using rails [Postgresql]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-postgresql

Using Active Record, How to order by 2 columns (created_at, views):

1st: the records created within the last 3 days

2nd: everything after that should be ordered only by views

In order to get a result similar to this (please disregard the date syntax):

```
[[2017-02-15 00:00:00 UTC, 150]],
 [2017-02-14 00:00:00 UTC, 88],
 [2017-02-13 00:00:00 UTC, 12]],
 [2016-01-14 00:00:00 UTC, 99999]],
 [2016-03-10 00:00:00 UTC, 3000]],
 [2016-11-07 00:00:00 UTC, 2000]],
 [2016-10-21 00:00:00 UTC, 1000]],
 [2016-09-03 00:00:00 UTC, 100]],
 [2016-05-18 00:00:00 UTC, 10]]
```

I found "date_trunc" in Postgresql but I need the last 3 days only once, and then just consider the number of views.

Which options do I have, ideally using just one query?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer, may not be a single query. But, It fulfils your requirement.

I am taking `User` model as an example.

**First, get the users whose created date is in last 3 days.**

`users = User.where(:created_at => (Date.today - 3.days)..Date.today)`

**Now, get the users whose created date is not in last 3 days, order by views DESC**

```
users2 = (User.where.not(:created_at => (Date.today - 3.days)..Date.today)).order('views desc')
```

Now, combining the two results using **`(+)`**

**Rails Active Record objects can be merged using `(+)`**

**`users3 = users + users2`** gives your result.

Comment: Thanks Sravan, that works. I'm still looking for a single query solution though.

Comment: yes, I will also keep trying. You can accept it if you find it useful.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can't be done in a single query. I'd go with the answer given by @Sravan

Answer (score 0):

You can do created date in between current date and current date - 3.days. Here you will get all the records which were created from last  3 days.

```
current_date = Time.zone.now
before_date = current_date - 3.days

Ex: where(:created_at => before_date.beginning_of_day.. current_date.end_of_day).order(created_at ASC, views DESC)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only shows the last 3 days. All the records need to be shown, having the ones created within the last 3 days at the top.